# Recursive CTE with multiple valid same parent child relationships

Tags: t-sql

I have an equipment inventory application I am working on.  The piece of equipment is my top level and it contains assemblies, sub-assemblies and parts.   I am trying to use recursive CTE to display the parent/child relationships.  The issue I am having is that some assemblies can have multiple sub-assemblies that are the same, meaning there is not difference in the part numbers.  This is causing my query to not show the correct relationship based on my order by statement.   This is the first time I have used CTE so I have be using a lot learned on the web.

PartNumberID 174 is used twice in this assembly.

```
    Sample  Table   
    equipmentID   parentPartNumberID  partNumberID
       17                1              281
       17              281              156
       17              156              161
       17              161              224
       17              281              174
       17              174              192
       17              192               56
       17              174              193
       17              281              174
       17              174              192
       17              192               56
       17              174              193
       17              281              283
       17   `          283              183
       17              283              277
       17              283              173

     Results of Query
    PARENT      CHILD   PARTLEVEL   HIERARCHY
      1           281       0         281
    281           156       1         281.156
    156           161       2         281.156.161
    161           224       3         281.156.161.224
    281           174       1         281.174
    281           174       1         281.174
    174           192       2         281.174.192
    174           192       2         281.174.192
    192            56       3         281.174.192.56
    192            56       3         281.174.192.56
    174           193       2         281.174.193
    174           193       2         281.174.193
    281           283       1         281.283
    283           173       2         281.283.173
    283           183       2         281.283.183
    283           277       2         281.283.277
```

As you can see the hierarchy is created correctly but I it is not being returned correctly because there is nothing unique for these 2 assemblies for the order by statement.

The Code:

```
with parts(PARENT,CHILD,PARTLEVEL,HIERARCHY) as (select parentPartNumberID,
---  Used to get rid of duplicates
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY partNumberID ORDER BY partNumberID) > 1
    THEN NULL 
    ELSE partNumberID END AS  partNumberID,
   0,
  CAST( partNumberID as nvarchar) as PARTLEVEL 
  FROM db.tbl_ELEMENTS
  WHERE parentPartNumberID=1 and equiptmentID=17

  UNION ALL
  SELECT part1.parentPartNumberId,
         ---  Used to get rid of duplicates
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parts1.partNumberID ORDER BY parts1.partNumberID) > 1
    THEN 10000 + parts1.partNumberID  
    ELSE parts1.partNumberID END,
            PARTLEVEL+1,
   cast(parts.hierarchy + '.' + CAST(parts1.partNumberID as nvarchar) as nvarchar)
          from dbo.tbl_BOM_Elements as parts1 inner 
                   join parts onparts1.parentPartNumberID=parts.CHILD 
          where id =17)

    select CASE WHEN PARENT > 10000
    THEN PARENT - 10000
    ELSE PARENT END AS PARENT,
    CASE WHEN CHILD > 10000
    THEN CHILD - 10000
    ELSE CHILD END AS CHILD,
            PARTLEVEL,HIERARCHY
    from parts
    order by hierarchy
```

I tried to create a unique ID to order but was not successful.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain more about, "I tried to create a unique ID to order but was not successful?"

Comment: Sure, I was trying to create a sequential ID dynamically as the “parts” (cte-Name) data was created so that I had a unique field that I could order by. This I think would allow for multiple same sub-assemblies.   Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by just answering the part about getting a sequential id.

If you have control you could just a unique Id to your source table. Having a surrogate primary key would be pretty typical here.

You could instead use a second CTE before the recursive one and add the row numbers there using ROW_NUMBER() OVER BY (ORDER BY equipmentID, parentPartNumberID,  partNumberID). Then build your recursive CTE off of that rather than the source table directly.

Better might be to use the first CTE to instead GROUP BY equipmentID, parentPartNumberID,  partNumberID and add a COUNT(1) field. This would let you instead use the count in you hierarchy rather than getting the duplicates. Something like 281.283.277x2 or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestions before I change my source table.  I had a feeling that changing the table might be the easiest route  ... Tim

Comment: I ended up changing my source table since there is not a lot of data. I then order by the new unique id and I get the view I need. This in my case was the easiest solution. Karl thank you for you help